# Why get different results when comparing two dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, comparison

I am comparing two df, it gives me `False` when using `.equals()`, but if I append two df together and use `drop_duplicate()` it gives me nothing. Can someone explain this?

Comment: Doesn't "False" mean that there are no duplicates in the 2 datasets? Therefore "drop_duplicate()" will return nothing.

Comment: You're going to need to provide a [mcve]. I can guarantee that `.drop_duplicates()` should not return an empty DataFrame, unless you started with an empty DataFrame, or specify `keep=False`

Comment: This question is way too broad.

Comment: yes I used 'keep=False' there's only column index left, not sure if I did this right, I'll try to get a minimal reproducible example after dinner.

Comment: @PySeeker I think 'False' in '.equals()' means different whereas ''True'' means two files are the same

Answer (score 2):

#### TL;DR

These are completely different operations and I'd have never expected them to produce the same results.

#### `pandas.DataFrame.equals`

Will return a boolean value depending on whether Pandas determines that the dataframes being compared are the "same".  That means that the index of one is the "same" as the index of the other, the columns of one is the "same" as the columns of the the other, and the data of one is the "same" as the data of the other.

See [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.equals.html)

It is **NOT** the same as `pandas.DataFrame.eq` which will return a dataframe of boolean values.

#### Setup

Consider these three dataframes

```
df0 = pd.DataFrame([[0, 1], [2, 3]], [0, 1], ['A', 'B'])
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 0], [3, 2]], [0, 1], ['B', 'A'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[0, 1], [2, 3]], ['foo', 'bar'], ['A', 'B'])

df0              df1              df2      

   A  B             B  A               A  B
0  0  1          0  1  0          foo  0  1
1  2  3          1  3  2          bar  2  3
```

If we checked if `df1` was `equals` to `df0`, we get

```
df0.equals(df1)

False
```

Even though all elements are the same

```
df0.eq(df1).all().all()

True
```

And that is because the columns are not aligned.  If I sort the columns then ...

```
df0.equals(df1.sort_index(axis=1))

True
```

---

#### `pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates`

Compares the values in rows and doesn't care about the index.

So, both of these produce the same looking results

```
df0.append(df2).drop_duplicates()
```

and

```
df0.append(df1, sort=True).drop_duplicates()

   A  B
0  0  1
1  2  3
```

When I `append` (or `pandas.concat`), Pandas will align the columns and add the appended dataframe as new rows.  Then `drop_duplicates` does it's thing.  But it was the inherent aligning of the columns that does the what I did above with `sort_index` and `axis=1`.

Comment: Thanks, this is very clear, the only thing is the result of 'drop.duplicates' give me duplicated rows, but I want to find the difference between two df (according to the index,i.e. ID), which means if they are the same, I want a blank output, if there's different, I want to see the difference, another thing is my data is very messy, one column contains different variables for each row, which makes it difficult to compare.

Comment: Update, I found the problem, EXCEL & csv rounded some numbers automatically so that the code cannot spot the difference, I've fixed it. Now after using drop_duplicates(), it gives me the rows which have difference but doesn't tell me which column or which value is different, is there a way for doing this? (I have 500ish columns and I'm only finding the difference manually at the moment)

Comment: I suggest posting a new question asking how to identify where the differences are.

Answer (score 0):

maybe the lines in both dataframes are not ordered the same way? dataframes will be equal when the lines corresponding to the same index are the same